# How to reference the package prompt box in the development of idea plug-in

Tags: intellij-plugin

I want to enter the package path in the text box of the custom jframe when prompted as shown below how should the box be written code?

The ideaIU2021.2 version is used.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGE6i.png)

How is the code written? Do you need to introduce other plugins?